# Cardano GraphQL change default ip

Tags: cardano-node, docker, cardano-graphql

I did run the cardano-graphql in a server and now it's sync but I'd like to send requests from local to server ip. I did open the port on AWS but couldn't figure it out where and how to change the default path. I did check docker_compose.yaml file but couldn't find something like 127.0.0.1 or localhost. I'd like to change it to 0.0.0.0 but not sure which file should I configure to access outside requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is solved. After typing docker ps I realize that db_sync is not working properly and keeps restarting. Deleting RESTORE_SNAPSHOT parameter while starting graphql solved my issue it syncs from the genesis.